# Atualizar Python 3x

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

Tenho a versão 3.7.3 do Python (apenas para estudos) no meu **Raspbian Buster** e gostaria de atualiza-lo para a versão mais recente (3.8.3).

Já tentei utilizar `sudo apt update` e `sudo apt upgrade` mas o sistema não atualizou informando que os pacotes estão atualizados.

Como proceder neste caso?

Comment: pelo o pouco tempo que venho usando exclusivamente linux, notei que python só é atualizado para versões recentes quando os desenvolvedores da distro escolhem fazer, ai o apt update/upgrade vai funcionar, se vc quer python3.8 instalado vc teria que fazer isso explicitamente, trate como um segundo programa, um programa independente, e ja adiantando não exclua o python 3.7 pois pode haver funções do sistema dependentes desta versão e a exclusão pode quebrar o sistema, ja vi em foruns relatos de tal, não era rasp, mas melhor não arriscar

Answer (score 0):

O Python que vem no sistema é usado, dentre outras coisas, para rodar as diversas aplicações que estão instaladas e que foram feitas em Python. É claro que você pode usá-lo para programar em Python, mas a maioria das distribuições não vai ter a versão mais nova. Especialmente uma distribuição baseada no Debian (que prima pela estabilidade e não por estar "na crista da onda") como o Raspbian.

Já o Arch Linux, por exemplo, tem um modelo de "rolling release" e sempre está atualizado e nesse momento que escrevo a versão do Python no Arch é 3.8.2 (essa é a última versão até o momento e a 3.8.3 ainda está como "release candidate").

Mas o melhor mesmo quando se programa em Python é usar um ambiente virtual ao invés de usar o Python que vem com o sistema. Um ambiente virtual é isolado e separado do Python do sistema e com isso você pode usar differentes versões do Python e de quaisquer biblioteca que queria usar sem correr o risco de prejudicar alguma outra aplicação.

Para se trabalhar com ambientes virtuais existem algumas opções, incluindo distribuições completas (com repositórios próprios) como o [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) (provavelmetne a opção mais fácil). Com o anaconda você cria um ambiente virtual e especifica a versão exata do Python que quer usar.

Outras opções para usar ambientes virtuais são [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv), [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/), ou até o próprio módulo [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) que já vem no python 3. Mas acredito que essas opções só gerenciem as bibliotecas e não a versão do python (você trabalha com um python isolado, mas a mesma versão do sistema). Para trabalhar com diferentes versões do python tem o [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), que certamente é usado junto com algumas das opções para trabalhar com ambientes virtuais.